# Rate of flow of electrons in a simple circuit, given the current?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, charge, electrical-resistance

I have this question:

[image]

The correct answer is C.

I understand that the flow of electrons should be from Y to X because electrons flow opposite to "conventional current", which is from positive to negative.
However, I can't figure out how the rate was found out.

The formula is 
$$Q = It$$
where $Q$ is the charge, $I$ the current and $t$ the time for which the current is considered.
I know that the charge of a single electron is $1.6 \times {10^{-19}}$. And that the current is 4.8 A. But where do I go from there? Time in this case will only be 1 (for 1 second). I can see clearly that the answer was obtained by dividing: $\frac{4.8}{1.6 \times {10^{-19}}}$ But why, I don't understand. The formula for rate should simply be $$(\text{Total charge}) / (\text{one second})$$ but to get the given answer I rearrange the charge formula around, which just gives $ \frac{1}{t} = \frac{I}{Q}$ which doesn't make sense.

I know this is extremely simple but I don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: Why does $\frac{I}{Q} = \frac{1}{t}$ not make sense?

Comment: If $e$ is the charge of one electron, then the number of electrons required to make 1 Coulomb is $1/e$. And 1 amp is 1 Coulomb per second, so it's $1/e$ electrons per second.

Comment: @ACuriousMind because for this question, that would just mean that 4.8/1.6x10^-19 is 1/1, which is false, no?

Comment: You have $Q = I t$. Then say that $Q = -\text{number of electrons} \times e$ so that $\text{number of electrons} / t = -I / e$. Can you figure it out now?

Comment: Why the close vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about what exactly *the rate of flow of electrons* is? It is the *number of electrons per second* passing through! The *number of electrons* is not included in your expression, and that's the problem.

Let start over but this time with *the number of electrons* $n$ included:

$$Q=It \Leftrightarrow \\
en=It \Leftrightarrow\\
\frac{n}{t}=\frac{I}{e} \Leftrightarrow\\
$$

Total charge $Q$ is the sum of all the $n$ electron charges $e$, so $Q=ne$.

$n/t$ is *number of electrons ($n$) per second ($t$)*, exactly what you are looking for. This is clearly equal to $I/e$ as you guessed.

Of course if you divide through with $n$ you get the $\frac{1}{t}=\frac{I}{ne}=\frac{I}{Q}$ that you found.

Answer (score 2):

You have to think more carefully about what exactly $Q$,$I$ and $t$ signify: In
$$ Q = I t$$
$Q$ is the charge that is transported by the current $I$ during the time $t$. If you now write 
$$ \frac{I}{Q} = \frac{1}{t}$$
then this gives how many times a charge of $Q$ is transported by $I$ during one unit of time (second), since $t$ is the time to transport one $Q$, so $\frac{1}{t}$ is the number of $Q$ per unit of time.